# I want to create new form programmatically then add controls, and events upon them C#

Tags: c#, .net, forms

I want to create a form programmatically, then add controls to that for and handle click events on those controls, 
such as click on button should show impact on text box

```
namespace formwizard
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Form form = new Form();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {               
                form.Text = formtitle.Text;
                int count = Convert.ToInt32(FormName.Text);
                int i=1;
                while (i<= count)
                {
                    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                    tb.Text = "Text box"+ i.ToString();
                    Button bt = new Button();
                    bt.Text = "Button" + i.ToString();
                    tb.Location = new Point(15, i*20);
                    bt.Location = new Point(120, i*20);
                    bt.Name = "Button" + i.ToString();
                    form.Controls.Add(tb);
                    form.Controls.Add(bt);
                    bt.Click +=new EventHandler(bt_Click);
                    i++;
                }
                // form.Controls.Add(...);
                form.ShowDialog();      
        }

        void  bt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = (Button) sender;
            string a=btn.Text.Substring(6,btn.Text.Length-6);
            MessageBox.Show("You clicked Button "+a);  
        }
    }      
}
```

[image]

Comment: And what is your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct, the only problem I see is you haven't initialized a new instance of `Form`:

```
Form form2 = new Form();
//now add your controls to this form
//show form using "form2.ShowDialog()"
```